# Does anyone know how to remove this Bearing? (Rainbow Vacuum E2 TYPE12)

Tags: vacuum

How do you remove this bearing? Any special tool?

[image: TOP BEARING]

Comment: uae a bearing puller

Answer (score 1):

A drift if the press fit is small.

But as @jsotola  said a puller is best.

If the bearing is not to be reused then the races can be cut or split.